# How to span text across two buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap button group with two buttons and I want some text to span across the two of them.

They are Decrease and Increase buttons. So I have the text "Contrast" across the two buttons with a "-" on one button and a "+" on the other button.

I have overlayed(?) a div with the required text on top and used "pointer-events:none" to get it working - BUT I need it to work on older browsers (IE 10) that do not support pointer-events.

Is there an alternative/better way of doing it??

```
  <div class="btn-group">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:3px;text-align:center;width:100%;color:white;z-index:300;pointer-events: none;">
      <i style="left-padding:2px;vertical-align: middle;" class="fa fa-adjust fa-2x"></i>
      <div style="display:inline;top: 2px;position: relative;">Contrast</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      <br>&nbsp;<br>-
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn">
      <br>&nbsp;<br>+
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: When you say across, do you mean on top of the buttons, or above them? Also, why are you using pointer-events? One more thing, I would actually set the dimensions of your buttons instead of relying on `br` and `nbsp` to control the size.

Comment: Can you just put the text in a different `row` and remove the padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I changed the design so that there were separate buttons and did not use a word spanning the two buttons.